# Unresolved external symbol LNK2019 Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, unresolved-external

I have probably seen all the topics discussing this issue but I still can't fix it

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class input : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    input();

public slots:
  void text();


signals:
    void buttonclicked();


private:
    QWidget * w = new QWidget;
    QPushButton * ok = new QPushButton;
    QLineEdit * line = new QLineEdit;
    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout;
};
```

this is a really simple header without implementation yet
but when I build it to check the code it gives me this error and I can't really solve it

```
moc_clss.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl input::text(void)" (?text@input@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl input::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@input@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

so help please if you can .

Comment: Did you implement `void input::text()`?

Comment: *"this is a really simple header without implementation yet"* - Correct. That's what the linker is telling you as well. So please, do provide an implementation (or remove the `Q_OBJECT` so that the MOC compiler won't reference it).

Comment: yes but when i implemented it i got the same error so i removed the implementation to see what is the problem and it is still the same

Comment: If you had it implemented then you have to check why the source file that implemented it was not being compiled and linked into your executable. Maybe you forgot to save the source file before you built.

Comment: and yes I removed the Q_OBJECT as you said but it still gives me the exact same error

Comment: I am new to QCreator so how can I check that?

Comment: chnage `input();` to `void input();`

Comment: That is supposed to be the constructor. `input();` is correct. `void input();` is not correct.

Comment: yes it is already correct because this is the default constructor, not a function

Comment: right click on text(); click refactor and add definition.

Comment: "when i implemented it i got the same error" That's because you haven't built your implementation. You must prove it to yourself that the implementation is being built. Delete the project's build folder and build it again.